# Override table sorter order

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I want to override the ordering on tablesorter. Right now I have the following entries in my table that are dynamically added:

```
1 Active,34 Active, 453 Active, 3235 Active, inactive, inactive
```

The issue is that there is another column that I want all the Active entries to be sorted by, and not by the number in front of it.

Is it possible to do this with table sorter? if so how?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12907882/1505169). Might be what you want.

Comment: @PatrickQ this is not quite what I was looking for. I've tried to clear up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. What I had to do was use a tablesorter parser. I then use regular expressions to strip the number and spaces off the `Active` strings. Afterwards I replace `inactive` with the value of 1, and `active`, with the value of 2.  Then I can sort my table just off the active and inactive category and do further sorting on based of another column. Here is the code below:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  //give an id to the parser
  id: 'campaigns',
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    //remove any numbers and spaces in the string s
    var state = s.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
    //change inactive to a 1 and active to a 2
    return state.toLowerCase().replace(/inactive/,1).replace(/active/,2);
  },
  //sort on a numeric type
  type: 'numeric'
});

$(function() {
  $("table#game-data-table").tablesorter({
    //sort based off of active inactive, then off column 4,and finally off column 1
    sortList: [[1,1], [3,1], [0,0]],
    headers: {
    1: {
      sorter: 'campaigns'
    }
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: it would be "cleaner" to use this within the format function: `return /inactive/i.test(s) ? 1 : 2;`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// call the tablesorter plugin 
$("table").tablesorter({ 
    // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
    sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
});
```

});

Comment: yeah this is what I'm doing right now, but the issue is that it first sorts on the whole first column and then the third column. I want it to sort on just active or inactive on the first column, and then sort on the third column. If a field is active though, it has a number in front of it. So it could look like 10 Active. I essentially need table sorter to ignore the number in front of active. Do you know how to do this?